# Show submitted text in both divs with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and building a prototype chat app. There are two windows on the same page, one for a help agent and the other is the client (or person requesting help). When either the agent or client enters a message, the message should appear in both windows. However, my current version is only showing the associated user in each window, but not the message in both windows. Also need to keep the submit button inactive until the message box has text in it.

I've tried using `<button type="button" disabled={!this.state.email}>Button</button>` and adding `value={this.state.message} onChange={this.handleChange}` to the input field, but this has proven ineffective.

So, the first thing is how to get the message to show in both windows when either user has entered a message. Lastly, how can I set the button state correctly?

I have my app broken down as such:

`MessageList.js` and `MessageForm.js` are components that are injected into `User.js` and `Agent.js`, which are then injected into `App.js`

**MessageList.js**

```
class MessageList extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    this.node.scrollTop = this.node.scrollHeight
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MessageList" ref={(node) => (this.node = node)}>
        {this.props.messages.map((message, i) => (
            <Message key={i} {...message} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MessageList
```

**MessageForm.js**

```
class MessageForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onMessageSend: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.input.focus()
  }

  handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.onMessageSend(this.input.value)
    this.input.value = ""
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="MessageForm" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={(node) => (this.input = node)}
            placeholder="Enter Message..."
          />
        </div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button type="submit">
            Send
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default MessageForm
```

**User.js**

```
class User extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="User">
        <header>
          <p>You</p>
        </header>
        <MessageList messages={this.state.messages} />
        <MessageForm onMessageSend={this.handleNewMessage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

**Agent.js**

```
class Agent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Agent">
        <header>
          <p>Agent</p>
        </header>
        <MessageList messages={this.state.messages} />
        <MessageForm onMessageSend={this.handleNewMessage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Agent;
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    messages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    messages: [],
  }

  handleNewMessage = (text) => {
     this.setState({
        messages: [...this.state.messages, {me: true, author: "Me", body: text}, {me:  false, author: "Agent", body: text}]
     })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="agentWindow">
          <Agent />
        </div>
        <div className="userWindow">
          <User />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Message.js**

```
class Message extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    author: PropTypes.string,
    body: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    me: PropTypes.bool,
  }

  render() {
    const classes = classNames('Message', {
      log: !this.props.author,
      me: this.props.me
    })

    return (
      <div className={classes}>
        {this.props.author && (
          <span className="author">{this.props.author}:</span>
        )}
        {this.props.body}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Message
```

Comment: What's the definition of the ```Message``` component in ```MessageList.js

```?

Comment: @salman.zare - it loops over the messages array and displays each message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your messages are not displaying on both windows because you are creating the state inside `Agent` and inside `User` and they are independent. So if you add a message to one, it wouldn't add to another state. You can take a look at [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to share state between components, or you can put your `messages` state as well as your `handleNewMessage` method inside `App` and pass them as props to `Agent` and `User`, this way they will be using the same state. Take a look:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: []
    }
    this.handleNewMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    messages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
  }

  handleNewMessage = (text) => {
     this.setState({
        messages: [...this.state.messages, {me: true, author: "Me", body: text}, {me:  false, author: "Agent", body: text}]
     })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="agentWindow">
          <Agent messages={this.state.messages} handleNewMessage={this.handleNewMessage} />
        </div>
        <div className="userWindow">
          <User messages={this.state.messages} handleNewMessage={this.handleNewMessage} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**User.js**

```
class User extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="User">
        <header>
          <p>You</p>
        </header>
        <MessageList messages={this.props.messages} />
        <MessageForm onMessageSend={this.props.handleNewMessage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

The same for `Agent`.

About the disabled button, you can add a controlled input, it would look like this:

```
class ExampleForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <button type="submit" disabled={this.state.message === ''}>Send<button/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've reworked my code based on your recommendations, but now getting an error `TypeError: _this.props.onMessageSend is not a function` on submit and no message is showing. I've also updated my original code above.

Comment: Edited my answer above.

Comment: I believe I'm almost there (thank you!), but I'm still getting one error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of null` which is happening in `App.js` for `<Agent messages={this.state.messages} handleNewMessage={this.handleNewMessage} />` Both User.js and Agent.js are identical and I've updated App.js as well.

Thoughts?

Comment: Realized I missed a file in the project that structures the actual messages (Message.js). I've added it above. However, still can't figure out why I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of null`

Any ideas?

Comment: @matt, can you change the following section in the ```MessageList.js```:

{this.props.messages && this.props.messages.map((message, i) => (
          <Message key={i} {...message} />
        ))}

Comment: @salman.zare - same issue still occurs: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of null`

Comment: @TiagoAlves - have you had success with the above solutions?

Comment: I'm on my phone, I'll take a look soon.

Comment: Does it occur just with `Agent` ?

Comment: @TiagoAlves - Nope. If you remove Agent and only have User, it gives the same error.

Comment: @TiagoAlves - Here's a plunker with all of the files and current state: http://plnkr.co/edit/FAPf7y0wK0ZlfQPkHlFY?p=preview

Comment: Edited above, you have to create the state in `App`

Comment: @TiagoAlves - really appreciate you continuing to help. That last edit did the trick! Now I just need to figure out how to only have the currently sent message show in each window, instead of both names at the same time. That's a whole separate issue though...many thanks!